# Front-end testing - tools Selenium RC

Tags: testing, selenium, frontend

I am wondering what tool(s) do you use for front-end testing...

Currently I am using Selenium RC as tool to test the front-end. I am quite happy with the result as I managed to integrate it with the ms build process etc. The problem with Selenium tests is that they are not always reliable especially if you browse with something else than Firefox.

I am looking for open source alternatives (tools for front-end testing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), we're also using [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/). However, it is because of its speed and it is used only for "quick & fast" tests, I'm afraid not a lot of things are better then selenium out there.

On the other hand, I find Selenium quite reliable, even in another browsers - it's just hard to build tests in such way, to think about race conditions etc.

Comment: I will check it out. I just want to look for alternatives. Not that Selenium is bad solution, but it's not THE only solution.

Comment: Then You also might want to check cuckoo, I've heard praise for it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) which can use Selenium as a backend, or HTMLUnit. It also allows you to do a myriad of other testing. It also works around several of the problems Selenium has, making it a bit easier to user than Selenium directly.

Answer (score 2):

My experience shows, [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) works the best from everything I tried. Even now I work with Firefox 6 and Selenium IDE works perfectly with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of Watin ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tool named cypress.
With cypress it is possible to write
End-to-end tests, Integration tests & Unit tests.

It is open source.
Learning curve is very low.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress